# SSL exception cURL error 35

Tags: ssl, handshake, sslhandshakeexception, gtmetrix

I was doing a rutinary check of my web at GTMETRIX when I get this error message:

> Analysis Error An error occurred fetching the page: HTTPS error: SSL
>   connect attempt failed error:14077410:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
>
> There may be a connectivity issue between your server and the GTmetrix
>   test server. Try testing from another test location or try again
>   later.

I was looking for answers but can't find any solution. This is the actual status of my SLL configuration:

> ** Configuring SSL ** testing htaccess rules...
>
> htaccess rules test failed with error: cURL error 35:
>   error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
>   handshake failure checking if .htaccess can or should be edited...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Common web servers do no longer accept SSLv3 connection requests (indicated by SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO). I would assume that the client component is very old or uses an outdated SSL library. Upgrade it to a newer version or recompile it using a current SSL library.